Is it possible to develop an Arduino library outside of the documents folder?
I'm starting to develop an Arduino library and am following the instructions at Writing a Library for Arduino. Those instructions show putting the library code in a sketch for development

First, make a Morse directory inside of the libraries sub-directory of your sketchbook directory. Copy or move the Morse.h and Morse.cpp files into that directory. Now launch the Arduino environment. If you open the Sketch > Import Library menu, you should see Morse inside. The library will be compiled with sketches that use it. If the library doesn't seem to build, make sure that the files really end in .cpp and .h (with no extra .ino, .pde or .txt extension, for example).

My library does not show in Sketch->Import Library and I get a compile error in in .ino file. If I move the library over to documents\arduino\libraries it is found, but that's not a good place for initial dev work.
I've worked up a tiny, but complete, example:
D:\projects\Arduino\LibraryDev\LibraryDev.ino
D:\projects\Arduino\LibraryDev\libraries\CoolLibrary\library.properties
D:\projects\Arduino\LibraryDev\libraries\CoolLibrary\src\CoolLibrary.cpp
D:\projects\Arduino\LibraryDev\libraries\CoolLibrary\src\CoolLibrary.h

D:\projects\Arduino\LibraryDev\LibraryDev.ino:2:10: fatal error: CoolLibrary.h: No such file or directory

LibraryDev.ino
#include <Arduino.h>
#include "CoolLibrary.h"

void setup (void)
{

}

void loop (void)
{
   
}

library.properties (Mostly a direct copy from the example)
name=CoolLibrary
version=1.0.0
author=Cristian Maglie <c.maglie@example.com>, Pippo Pluto <pippo@example.com>
maintainer=Cristian Maglie <c.maglie@example.com>
sentence=A library that makes coding a Webserver a breeze.
paragraph=Supports HTTP1.1 and you can do GET and POST.
category=Communication
url=http://example.com/
architectures=*
depends=ArduinoHttpClient

CoolLibrary.cpp
#include "CoolLibrary.h"

void CoolLibaray::nothing (void)
{
}


CoolLibrary.h
class CoolLibaray
{
   void nothing (void);
};



Is the example just wrong, or is there some kind of extra configuration I need to do?
Comments telling me to move from Arduino IDE to a different development environment will be ignored.
OS: Window 10
Arduino IDE: 2.3.2

Seems to me that you didn't follow the example to the letter... You decided for yourself that your files should not be in that directory, even though the example asks you to put it there... To me, it looks like that is your problem.
My advice is: follow the example to the letter first (just so you know what to do exactly and why), then start your work. When in doubt, do develop in the directory you want to avoid (it's not really a big deal, as you are the only user, so... ?)

The example says to put them in libraries<libaryname>\src which is exactly where I put them. Where do you think it is telling me to put them?

Where did you find the "src" part?

watch out for typos btw, although they seem consistent in you question: class CoolLib*aray*

The src came from https://arduino.github.io/arduino-cli/1.0/library-specification/
I didn't mention that I've tried it in both the 1.0 way (no src, no library.properties) and the 1.5 way (with src). Both give the same issue.
You got me on the spelling . But, as you say, it's consistent.

You could try to fix this include statement:
#include "CoolLibrary.h"
to
#include "/libraries/CoolLibrary/src/CoolLibrary.h"
